# Electron Js not sending XMLHTTPRequest

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am relatively new to Electron. I am trying to send data from my electron app to a fiscal device using XMLHTTPRequest but electron is not sending the request. I have tried to change XMLHTTPRequest to xhr2 but still get the same error. I am guessing that chromium
is refusing to send the data but I am not sure. Can someone please help me out here.

```
/** @namespace */
var Tremol = Tremol || {};
Tremol.FP = Tremol.FP ||
  /** 
   * Tremol fiscal printer javascript library. Usage: var fp = new Tremol.FP();
   * @constructor
   * @class FP
   * @classdesc Tremol fiscal printer javascript library.
   * @memberof Tremol
   * @instance
   */
  function () {
    if (!(this instanceof Tremol.FP)) {
      return new Tremol.FP();
    }
    this.prototype = this;
    var coreVersion = "1.0.0.8";
    var ip = "localhost";
    var port = 4444;
    var url = "http://localhost:4444/";
    var w = false;
    var defsSent = false;
    var ok = false;
    var psr = (typeof DOMParser !== 'undefined' ? new DOMParser() : (typeof ActiveXObject !== 'undefined' ? new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM') : function () { throw new Error(); }));
    var req = (typeof XMLHttpRequest !== 'undefined' ? new XMLHttpRequest() : (typeof ActiveXObject !== 'undefined' ? new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : function () { throw new Error(); }));
    try { req.withCredentials = false; } catch (ignored) { };
    try { req.overrideMimeType("text/xml; charset=UTF-8"); } catch (ignored) { };
    var sendReq = function (verb, prefix, data) {
      try {
        req.open(verb, url + prefix, false);
        req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
        // try { req.setRequestHeader("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"); } catch (ignored) { }
        req.send(data);
        console.log(data)
        if (req.status !== 200) {
          throw new Error("HTTP code " + req.status);
        }
        var respXml = req.responseXML;
        if (!respXml || respXml.length === 0) {
          try {
            if (req.responseText && req.responseText.length > 0) {
              respXml = psr.parseFromString(req.responseText);
            } else {
              throw new Error();
            }
          }
          catch (ignored) {
            throw new Tremol.ServerError("Server response missing", Tremol.ServerErrorType.ServerResponseMissing);
          }
        }
        throwOnServerError(respXml);
        return respXml;
      }
      catch (ex) {
        if (ex instanceof Tremol.ServerError) {
          throw ex;
        }
        else {
          throw new Tremol.ServerError("Server connection error (" + ex.message + ")", Tremol.ServerErrorType.ServerConnectionError)
        }
      }
    };

    var throwOnServerError = function (resp) {
      console.log(resp)
      var resRoot = resp.getElementsByTagName("Res")[0];
      var resCode = Number(resRoot.getAttribute("Code"));
      if (resCode !== 0) {
        var errNode = resp.getElementsByTagName("Err")[0];
        /** var source = errNode.getAttribute("Source"); */
        var errMsg = resp.getElementsByTagName("Message")[0].firstChild.data;
        if (resCode === 40) {
          var ste1 = parseInt(errNode.getAttribute("STE1"), 16);
          var ste2 = parseInt(errNode.getAttribute("STE2"), 16);
          var fpliberror = parseInt(errNode.getAttribute("FPLibErrorCode"), 16);
          throw new Tremol.ServerError(errMsg, resCode, ste1, ste2, fpliberror);
        }
        else {
          throw new Tremol.ServerError(errMsg, resCode);
        }
      }
    }

    var analyzeResponse = function (resp) {
      console.log(resp)
      var resRoot = resp.getElementsByTagName("Res")[0];
      var props = resRoot.getElementsByTagName("Res");
      var resultObj = {};
      var name = "";
      var p = 0;
      for (; p < props.length; p++) {
        var prop = props[p];
        var type = prop.getAttribute("Type");
        name = prop.getAttribute("Name");
        var value = prop.getAttribute("Value");
        if (value === "@") {
          resultObj[name] = null;
          break;
        }
        if (name === "Reserve") {
          continue; /** SKIP */
        }
        switch (type) {
          case "Text":
            resultObj[name] = value;
            break;
          case "Number":
            resultObj[name] = parseFloat(value);
            break;
          case "Decimal":
            resultObj[name] = parseFloat(value);
            break;
          case "Option":
            resultObj[name] = value;
            break;
          case "DateTime":
            resultObj[name] = value.parseDateWithFormat(Date.TremolFpFormat);
            break;
          case "Reserve":
          case "OptionHardcoded":
            continue; /** SKIP */
          case "Base64":
            resultObj[name] = String(value).base64stringToArrayBuffer();
            break;
          case "Decimal_with_format":
            resultObj[name] = parseFloat(value);
            break;
          case "Decimal_plus_80h":
            resultObj[name] = parseFloat(value);
            break;
          case "Status":
            resultObj[name] = (value === "1")
            break;
          case "Null":
            resultObj[name] = null;
            break;
          default: /** unknown type => string */
            resultObj[name] = value;
            break;
        }
      }
      w = false;
      if (p === 1) {
        return resultObj[name];
      }
      else {
        return resultObj;
      }
    };

    /**
     * Returns the version of the core library
     * @returns {string}
     */
    this.GetVersionCore = function () {
      return coreVersion;
    };

    /**
     * Returns the version of the generated library
     * @returns {number}
     */
    this.GetVersionDefinitions = function () {
      if (this.prototype.timeStamp) {
        return this.prototype.timeStamp;
      }
      else {
        return 0;
      }
    };

    /**
     * Returns true if there is a command which is currently in progress 
     * @returns {boolean}
     */
    this.IsWorking = function () {
      return w;
    };

    /** 
     * Returns true if server definitions and generated code are with the same versions 
     * @returns {boolean}
     */
    this.IsCompatible = function () {
      return ok;
    };

    /**
     * Sends command to ZfpLab server
     * @param {string} commandName The name of the command
     * @param {...*} var_args Command arguments(ArgumentName, ArgumentValue, ArgumentName2, ArgumentValue2)
     * @return {*} 
     * @throws {Error}
     */
    this.do = function (commandName) {
      w = true;
      try {
        if (arguments.length < 1) {
          throw new Error("Invalid number of arguments!");
        }
        if ((arguments.length % 2) === 0) {
          throw new Error("Invalid number of arguments!");
        }

        /** var xml = psr.parseFromString("<Command></Command>", "text/xml");
        var rt = xml.getElementsByTagName("Command")[0];
        rt.setAttribute("Name", commandName);
        if(arguments.length > 1)
        {
            var as = xml.createElement("Args");
            rt.appendChild(as);
            for (var a = 1; a < arguments.length; a+=2) 
            {
                var an = xml.createElement("Arg");
                an.setAttribute("Name", arguments[a]);
                if(typeof arguments[a + 1]  === "string")
                {
                    an.setAttribute("Value", arguments[a + 1].escapeForXML());
                }
                else if(arguments[a + 1] instanceof Date)
                {
                    an.setAttribute("Value", arguments[a + 1].toTremolFpString());
                }
                else if (arguments[a + 1] instanceof Uint8Array)
                {
                    an.setAttribute("Value", arguments[a + 1].toBase64string());
                }
                else
                {
                    an.setAttribute("Value", arguments[a + 1]);
                }
                as.appendChild(an);
            }
        }
        var response = sendReq("POST", "", xml); */

        var x = '<Command Name="' + commandName + '">';
        if (arguments.length > 1) {
          x += "<Args>";
          for (var a = 1; a < arguments.length; a += 2) {
            if (typeof arguments[a + 1] === "string") {
              x += '<Arg Name="' + arguments[a] + '" Value="' + arguments[a + 1].escapeForXML() + '" />';
            }
            else if (arguments[a + 1] instanceof Date) {
              x += '<Arg Name="' + arguments[a] + '" Value="' + arguments[a + 1].toTremolFpString() + '" />';
            }
            else if (arguments[a + 1] instanceof Uint8Array) {
              x += '<Arg Name="' + arguments[a] + '" Value="' + arguments[a + 1].toBase64string() + '" />';
            }
            else if (typeof arguments[a] === "undefined" || typeof arguments[a + 1] === "undefined" || arguments[a] == null || arguments[a + 1] == null) {
              continue;
            }
            else {
              x += '<Arg Name="' + arguments[a] + '" Value="' + String(arguments[a + 1]).escapeForXML() + '" />';
            }
          }
          x += "</Args>";
        }
        x += "</Command>";
        var response = sendReq("POST", "", x);
        return analyzeResponse(response);
      }
      catch (ex) {
        if (ex instanceof Tremol.ServerError) {
          throw ex;
        }
        else {
          throw new Tremol.ServerError(ex.message, Tremol.ServerErrorType.ServerErr);
        }
      }
      finally {
        w = false;
      }
    };

    /**
     * Gets ZfpLab server settings 
     * @returns {Tremol.FP.ServerSettings}
     */
    this.ServerGetSettings = function () {
      return { ipaddress: ip, tcpport: port };
    };

    /**
     * @param {string} ipaddress Sets IP address
     * @param {number} tcpport Sets TCP port
     */
    this.ServerSetSettings = function (ipaddress, tcpport) {
      ip = ipaddress;
      port = tcpport;
      url = ip;
      if (url.indexOf("//") === -1 && url.indexOf("http") === -1 && url.indexOf("https") === -1) {
        url = "//" + url;
      }
      if (port && port > 0) {
        url += (":" + port);
      }
      if (url.charAt(url.length - 1) !== "/") {
        url += "/";
      }
    };

    /**
     * Find device connected on serial port or USB
     * @returns {Tremol.FP.DeviceSettings}
     */
    this.ServerFindDevice = function () {
      w = true;
      try {
        var response = sendReq("GET", "finddevice", null);
        if (response.getElementsByTagName("com")[0].firstChild) {
          var comS = response.getElementsByTagName("com")[0].firstChild.nodeValue; //.data
          var baudS = Number(response.getElementsByTagName("baud")[0].firstChild.nodeValue);
          var fps = { serialPort: comS, baudRate: baudS, isWorkingOnTcp: false };
          return fps;
        }
        return null;
      }
      finally {
        w = false;
      }
    }

    /**
     * Gets the device settings
     * @returns {Tremol.FP.DeviceSettings}
     */
    this.ServerGetDeviceSettings = function () {
      w = true;
      try {
        var response = sendReq("GET", "settings", null);
        var isTcp = Boolean(response.getElementsByTagName("tcp")[0].firstChild.nodeValue);
        var comS = response.getElementsByTagName("com")[0].firstChild.nodeValue; //.data
        var baudS = Number(response.getElementsByTagName("baud")[0].firstChild.nodeValue);
        var ipS = response.getElementsByTagName("ip")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
        var portS = Number(response.getElementsByTagName("port")[0].firstChild.nodeValue);
        var passS = response.getElementsByTagName("password")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
        var portOpen = Boolean(response.getElementsByTagName("keepPortOpen")[0].firstChild.nodeValue);
        var df = response.getElementsByTagName("defVer");
        if (this.prototype.timeStamp && df.length > 0) {
          ok = (this.prototype.timeStamp === Number(df[0].firstChild.nodeValue));
        }
        var fps = { isWorkingOnTcp: isTcp, ipaddress: ipS, tcpPort: portS, password: passS, serialPort: comS, baudRate: baudS, keepPortOpen: portOpen };
        return fps;
      }
      finally {
        w = false;
      }
    };


    /**
     * Sets Device Bluetooth communication settings if ZFPLabServer is running on Android device.
     * @throws {Error}
     * @param {string} deviceFriendlyName Bluetooth Device friendly name (ZK900001)
     */
    this.ServerSetAndroidBluetoothDeviceSettings = function (deviceFriendlyName) {
      w = true;
      try {
        if (!Tremol.FP.IsOnAndroid()) {
          throw new Tremol.ServerError("This connection type is used only if ZFPLabServer is running on Android device", Tremol.ServerErrorType.ClientArgValueWrongFormat);
        }
        var response = sendReq("GET", "settings(com=" + deviceFriendlyName + ",tcp=0)", null);
        var df = response.getElementsByTagName("defVer");
        if (this.prototype.timeStamp && df.length > 0) {
          ok = (this.prototype.timeStamp === Number(df[0].firstChild.nodeValue));
        }
      }
      finally {
        w = false;
      }
    };

    /**
     * Sets Device serial port communication settings
     * This method is also used to set Bluetooth connection if ZFPLabServer is running on Android device.
     * @throws {Error}
     * @param {string} serialPort The name of the serial port (example: COM1).
     * @param {number} baudRate Baud rate (9600, 19200, 38400, 57600, 115200).
     * @param {boolean} keepPortOpen Keeps serial port open. For Bluetooth connection - not used.
     */
    this.ServerSetDeviceSerialSettings = function (serialPort, baudRate, keepPortOpen) {
      w = true;
      try {
        var response = sendReq("GET", "settings(com=" + serialPort + ",baud=" + baudRate + ",keepPortOpen=" + (keepPortOpen ? "1" : "0") + ",tcp=0)", null);
        var df = response.getElementsByTagName("defVer");
        if (this.prototype.timeStamp && df.length > 0) {
          ok = (this.prototype.timeStamp === Number(df[0].firstChild.nodeValue));
        }
      }
      finally {
        w = false;
      }
    };

    /**
     * Sets Device LAN/WIFI communication settings
     * @throws {Error}
     * @param {string} ipaddress IP address
     * @param {number} tcpport TCP port
     * @param {string=} password ZFP password
     */
    this.ServerSetDeviceTcpSettings = function (ipaddress, tcpport, password) {
      w = true;
      try {
        var response = sendReq("GET", "settings(ip=" + ipaddress + ",port=" + tcpport + (password ? (",password=" + password) : "") + ",tcp=1)", null);
        var df = response.getElementsByTagName("defVer");
        if (this.prototype.timeStamp && df.length > 0) {
          ok = (this.prototype.timeStamp === Number(df[0].firstChild.nodeValue));
        }
      }
      finally {
        w = false;
      }
    };

    /**
     * Gets ZfpLab server connected clients
     * @throws {Error}
     * @return {Tremol.FP.ServerClient[]}  Connected clients
     */
    this.ServerGetClients = function () {
      w = true;
      try {
        var response = sendReq("GET", "clients", null);
        var clientNodes = response.getElementsByTagName("Client");
        var clients = [];
        for (var c = 0; c < clientNodes.length; c++) {
          var client = {
            id: response.getElementsByTagName("Id")[c].firstChild.nodeValue,
            ipaddress: response.getElementsByTagName("ip")[c].firstChild.nodeValue,
            isConnected: (response.getElementsByTagName("PortIsOpen")[c].firstChild.nodeValue === "1")
          };
          clients.push(client);
        }
        return clients;
      }
      finally {
        w = false;
      }
    };

    /**
     * Removes client from the server
     * @param {string} ip IP address of the client
     * @throws {Error}
     */
    this.ServerRemoveClient = function (ip) {
      w = true;
      try {
        sendReq("GET", "clientremove(ip=" + ip + ")", null);
      }
      finally {
        w = false;
      }
    };

    this.ServerSendDefs = function (defs) {
      w = true;
      try {
        if (!defsSent) {
          sendReq("POST", "", defs);
          defsSent = true;
        }
      }
      finally {
        w = false;
      }
    };

    /**
     * Closes the connection of the current client
     * @throws {Error}
     */
    this.ServerCloseDeviceConnection = function () {
      w = true;
      try {
        sendReq("GET", "clientremove(who=me)", null);
      }
      finally {
        w = false;
      }
    };

    /**
     * Removes all clients from the server
     * @throws {Error}
     */
    this.ServerRemoveAllClients = function () {
      w = true;
      try {
        sendReq("GET", "clientremove(who=all)", null);
      }
      finally {
        w = false;
      }
    };

    /**
    * Enables or disables ZfpLab server log
    * @throws {Error}
    * @param {boolean} enable enable the log
    */
    this.ServerSetLog = function (enable) {
      w = true;
      try {
        sendReq("GET", "log(on=" + (enable ? "1" : "0") + ")", null);
      }
      finally {
        w = false;
      }
    };
  };


Tremol.FP.IsOnAndroid = function () {
  return (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") > -1);
}

/** 
 * @typedef {Tremol.ServerErrorType} Tremol.ServerErrorType
 * @enum
 * @readonly
 */
Tremol.ServerErrorType = {
  /** @memberof Tremol.ServerErrorType */
  OK: 0,
  /** The current library version and the fiscal device firmware is not matching */
  ServMismatchBetweenDefinitionAndFPResult: 9,
  ServDefMissing: 10,
  ServArgDefMissing: 11,
  ServCreateCmdString: 12,
  ServUndefined: 19,
  /** When the server can not connect to the fiscal device */
  ServSockConnectionFailed: 30,
  /** Wrong device ТCP password */
  ServTCPAuth: 31,
  ServWrongTcpConnSettings: 32,
  ServWrongSerialPortConnSettings: 33,
  /** Proccessing of other clients command is taking too long */
  ServWaitOtherClientCmdProcessingTimeOut: 34,
  ServDisconnectOtherClientErr: 35,
  FPException: 40,
  ClientArgDefMissing: 50,
  ClientAttrDefMissing: 51,
  ClientArgValueWrongFormat: 52,
  ClientSettingsNotInitialized: 53,
  ClientInvalidGetFormat: 62,
  ClientInvalidPostFormat: 63,
  ServerAddressNotSet: 100,
  /** Specify server ServerAddress property */
  ServerConnectionError: 101,
  /** Connection from this app to the server is not established */
  ServerResponseMissing: 102,
  ServerResponseError: 103,
  /** The current library version and server definitions version do not match */
  ServerDefsMismatch: 104,
  ClientXMLCanNotParse: 105,
  PaymentNotSupported: 201,
  ServerErr: 1000
};
Object.freeze(Tremol.ServerErrorType);

/**
 * @constructor
 * @class FPError
 * @classdesc Error thrown from Tremol.FP library
 * @param {string} message
 * @param {Tremol.ServerErrorType} type
 * @param {number=} ste1
 * @param {number=} ste2
 * @param {fpliberror=} ste2
 */
Tremol.ServerError = function (message, type, ste1, ste2, fpliberror) {
  if (!(this instanceof Tremol.ServerError)) {
    return new Tremol.ServerError(message, type, ste1, ste2, fpliberror);
  }
  this.type = type;
  this.name = "Tremol.ZFPLabError";
  this.message = (message || "");
  this.ste1;
  this.ste2;
  if (ste1 !== undefined && ste1 !== null) {
    this.ste1 = ste1;
  }
  if (ste2 !== undefined && ste2 !== null) {
    this.ste2 = ste2;
  }
  if (fpliberror !== undefined && fpliberror !== null) {
    this.fpLibError = fpliberror;
  }
  this.isFpException = (this.type === Tremol.ServerErrorType.FPException);
};
Tremol.ServerError.prototype = Error;

Date.TremolFpFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss";

Date.prototype.toTremolFpString = function () {
  var d = this.getDate().lpad(2);
  var M = (this.getMonth() + 1).lpad(2);
  var y = this.getFullYear().lpad(4);
  var h = this.getHours().lpad(2);
  var m = this.getMinutes().lpad(2);
  var s = this.getSeconds().lpad(2);
  return d + "-" + M + "-" + y + " " + h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
};

Date.prototype.toStringWithFormat = function (format) {
  var f = format;
  var d = this.getDate();
  var M = (this.getMonth() + 1);
  var y = this.getFullYear();
  var h = this.getHours();
  var m = this.getMinutes();
  var s = this.getSeconds();
  f = f.replace("dd", d.lpad(2));
  f = f.replace("d", d); f
  f = f.replace("MM", M.lpad(2));
  f = f.replace("M", M);
  f = f.replace("yyyy", y.lpad(4));
  f = f.replace("yy", (y - 2000).lpad(2));
  f = f.replace("hh", h.lpad(2));
  f = f.replace("mm", m.lpad(2));
  f = f.replace("m", m);
  f = f.replace("ss", s.lpad(2));
  f = f.replace("s", s);
  return f;
};

Number.prototype.lpad = function (size) {
  var s = String(this);
  while (s.length < (size || 2)) { s = "0" + s; }
  return s;
};

String.prototype.parseDateWithFormat = function (format) {
  var p = this;
  var f = format;
  var y = 0;
  var M = 0;
  var d = 0;
  var h = 0;
  var m = 0;
  var s = 0;
  var yIx = f.indexOf("yyyy");
  var MIx = f.indexOf("MM");
  var dIx = f.indexOf("dd");
  var hIx = f.indexOf("HH");
  var mIx = f.indexOf("mm");
  var sIx = f.indexOf("ss");
  if (yIx !== -1) {
    y = parseInt(p.substring(yIx, yIx + 4));
  }
  else {
    yIx = f.indexOf("yy");
    if (yIx !== -1) {
      y = parseInt(p.substring(yIx, yIx + 2));
    }
  }
  if (MIx !== -1) {
    M = parseInt(p.substring(MIx, MIx + 2)) - 1;
  }
  if (dIx !== -1) {
    d = parseInt(p.substring(dIx, dIx + 2));
  }
  if (hIx !== -1) {
    h = parseInt(p.substring(hIx, hIx + 2));
  }
  if (mIx !== -1) {
    m = parseInt(p.substring(mIx, mIx + 2));
  }
  if (sIx !== -1) {
    s = parseInt(p.substring(sIx, sIx + 2));
  }
  return new Date(y, M, d, h, m, s);
};

/**
 * This method replaces all matches in the string
 * @this {string}
 * @param {string} search the string which should be replaced
 * @param {string} replacement the string which should be put for replacement
 */
String.prototype.replaceAll = function (search, replacement) {
  return this.replace(new RegExp(search.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1"), 'g'), replacement);
};

String.prototype.escapeForXML = function () {
  var ss = this.toString();
  ss = ss.replaceAll("&", '&amp;')
    .replaceAll("<", '&lt;')
    .replaceAll(">", '&gt;')
    .replaceAll('"', '&quot;')
    .replaceAll("'", '&apos;')
    .replaceAll("\n", '&#10;')
    .replaceAll("\r", '&#13;');
  return ss;
};

String.prototype.base64stringToArrayBuffer = function () {
  var binary_string = window.atob(this.toString());
  var len = binary_string.length;
  var bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    bytes[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return bytes;
};

Uint8Array.prototype.toBase64string = function () {
  var arr = this;
  var binary = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.byteLength; i++) {
    binary += String.fromCharCode(arr[i]);
  }
  return window.btoa(binary);
};

Uint8Array.prototype.toUnicodeString = function () {
  var arr = this;
  var res = ""

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.byteLength; i++) {
    res += String.fromCharCode(arr[i]);
  }
  return res;
};



/**
* @typedef {Object} Tremol.FP.ServerSettings
* @property {string} ipaddress IP address
* @property {number} tcpport TCP port
*/

/**
* @typedef {Object} Tremol.FP.DeviceSettings
* @property {boolean} isWorkingOnTcp True if device is working on tcp
* @property {string} serialPort Serial port (example: COM1). If ZFPLabServer is running on Android device - Device friendly name (ZK999999)
* @property {number} baudRate Baud rate (9600, 19200, 38400, 57600, 115200)
* @property {boolean} keepPortOpen Keeps the port opened
* @property {string} ipaddress IP address
* @property {number} tcpPort TCP port
* @property {string?} password ZFP wifi password
*/
/**
* @typedef {Object} Tremol.FP.ServerClient
* @property {string} id Client id
* @property {string} ipaddress IP address
* @property {boolean} isConnected The client is connected to device
*/
```

```
module.exports.load = function (paths) {
  var XMLHttpRequest = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest;
  var DOMParser = require('xmldom').DOMParser;
  for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
    eval(require('fs').readFileSync(paths[i], 'utf8'));
  }
  return Tremol;
}
```

My express file to get data

```
app.post('/total', (req, res) => {

  

  payload = req.body
  fp.ServerSetSettings("http://localhost:4444/");
  console.log(fp.ServerSetDeviceTcpSettings("196.207.27.42", 8000, "Password"))

  fp.ServerSetDeviceTcpSettings("196.207.19.131", 8000, "Password");
  if (device) {
    fp.ServerSetDeviceSerialSettings(device.serialPort, device.baudRate, false); //If FD is connected on serial port or USB
    fp.PrintDiagnostics();
  } else {
    console.log("Device not found")
  }
  payload = req.body
  print_host = req.headers.hostname;
  // printer_ip = req.headers.printerip + ':' + req.headers.printerport;

  fp.ServerSetSettings("http://localhost:4444/");
  fp.ServerSetDeviceTcpSettings("196.207.19.131", 8000, "Password");
  console.log(fp.ServerSetDeviceTcpSettings("196.207.19.131", 8000, "Password"))
  // fp.ServerSetSettings(print_host);
  // fp.ServerSetDeviceTcpSettings(req.headers.printerip, req.headers.printerport, req.headers.senderid);
  var device = fp.ServerFindDevice();

  if (device) {
    fp.ServerSetDeviceSerialSettings(device.serialPort, device.baudRate, false); //If FD is connected on serial port or USB
    fp.PrintDiagnostics();
  }
  else {
    let error = {
      "error_status": "Device Not Found"
    }

    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(error);
  }

  const status = fp.ReadStatus()
  if (status) {
    try {
      fp.OpenInvoiceWithFreeCustomerData("", payload.customer_pin, "", "", "", "", "", "")
      for (const val of payload.item_list) {
        let hscode = val.hscode ? val.hscode : ""
        fp.SellPLUfromExtDB(val.stockitemname, val.taxrateclass, val.rate, " ", hscode, " ", val.taxrate, val.qty, 0);
      }
      res.send({ "msg": "yess" })

    } catch (e) {
      let error = {
        "error_status": String(e)
      }
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      res.send(error);
    }
    const close = fp.CloseReceipt()
    res.json(close)
  }
}

)
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error but the app is not sending any request and receiving any response from the server.